# How get current segment in dos

Tags: c, dos

I am trying to get cs (current segment) register value by using c language. I tried it bay assembler by this code:

```
__asm__("movw %%eax, %%ecs;" : "=r" ( cur_seg ));
```

but my project did not recognise __asm__. May be there is other way to this? Please help.

Comment: What C compiler are you using?

Comment: `CS` is the Code Segment register

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is gcc-specifics, are you using gcc under dos? If not try to use __asm {}, _asm {} or asm {} syntax. See more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45yd4tzz(v=vs.80).aspx, http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/4927,